# Populating fresh theme installs with sections?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm developing a Shopify theme, and I notice that most themes include pre-constructed sections on the home page when you install it on your store. The Debut theme is a perfect example of this.

I know you can write **Presets** when you make your section, which gives it starting data, but that seems to only show up when you **ADD THE SECTION** as opposed to installing the theme. I want a certain number of sample sections to be visible out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it, you need to custom-add the sections, blocks, etc to the **schema_data.json** in the sections portion you need to add the filename of the section you want to have shown on the home page. Then during a fresh theme install it will be there.

Comment: This isn't the correct approach the settings_data should remain as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use the `{% schema %}` tag. See how the example is using `"presets"` Depending on whether the section is statically included or dynamically included on the index you should use `"preset"` or `"default"` you can read more about that [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/sections)

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "presets": [
      {
        "category": "Custom Content",
        "name": "Text",
        "settings": {
          "heading": "Hello World"
        },
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "settings": {
              "content": "Once upon a time..."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```